# Which Inca deities are shown in "Dora and the Lost City of Gold"?

Tags: historical-accuracy

In the movie [Dora and the Lost City of Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dora_and_the_Lost_City_of_Gold), when the kids enter the temple a giant monkey-like deity (made of gold) is shown. Which *Inca* deity is it?

Here is an image of the poster:

> [image: poster]

Two deities are shown:

1. The one on the entrance to the temple.

   > [image: entrance]
   >
   > Dora offers water
2. The one inside the temple.

   > [image: inside]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a real *Incan* deity, but an artistic creativity deriving inspiration from [Incan Sun God](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/704602304175525697/) [***Inti***](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Inti-Inca-Sun-god) and the [Howler Monkey God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howler_monkey_gods)

[image]

Comment: **Viracocha** created the universe, sun, moon, and stars, time (by commanding the sun to move over the sky) and civilization itself. **Inti** was one of the most important gods to the Inca people and known as the **sun god.**

Comment: @SeverusSnape: Corrected it. Should be good now.